# java multithreading ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, executorservice

I am trying to create multithreads for lucene indexing. Let's say I have a list of numeric numbers from 101 to 999. what I want to achieve is that split this list into different groups and each group is handled by different thread.

I am able to partition it to different group, however, when running multithreading, all threads only take the first partition (l[0]) in this case. 
for example, the above code creates 3 threads( t1,t2, t3) and I also have three partitions (p1,p2,p3)  where p1 [101,400], p2[401,600], p3[601,999]. Supposely, t1 runs on p1, t2 runs on p2 and t3 runs on p3. But now, all threads run on p1.

does anyone know how to fix it?

added changes based on Tim's suggestion, but still same result

```
final int BLOCK_SIZE = 1; 
AtomicInteger nextBlock = new AtomicInteger(0);
 int blockToProcess =  nextBlock.getAndIncrement(); 
 int endBlocks = (blockToProcess+partitions.size())*BLOCK_SIZE; 
 for(int i=BLOCK_SIZE*blockToProcess;i<endBlocks;i++)
 { 
  Myclass it=new Myclass(l);
  todo.add( Executors.callable(it));
  } 
 taskExecutor.invokeAll(todo);
```

For partitioning, I used Guava library and confirmed with output, so partitions seems ok

I tried following as well, still same result. Actually, the following was what I had at first place.

```
 for(int i=0;i<partitions.size;i++)
{ 
Myclass it=new Myclass(partitions.get(i)); 
taskExecutor.execute(it);
 }
```

---

to make things easier and cleaner, I just created whole new testing files as following
there are two classes: Test and TestThreads
For Test class

```
    public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int numOfthreads=2;
    List<String> originalList=new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        originalList.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }

    int partitionSize = IntMath.divide(originalList.size(), numOfthreads, RoundingMode.UP);
    List<List<String>> partitions=Lists.partition(originalList, partitionSize);
    List<Callable<Object>> todo = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();
    int count=0;
    ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfthreads);

      for(int i=0;i<partitions.size();i++)
      { 
          TestThreads  it=new TestThreads(partitions.get(i));

            todo.add( Executors.callable(it));
             System.out.println("Created thread " +count+", containing: "
             +partitions.get(i).size()+" files\n");
             for(String s:partitions.get(i))
             {
                 System.out.print(s+" ");
             }
             count++;
             System.out.println("\n");
         }

        taskExecutor.invokeAll(todo);

}

 }
```

For TestThreads class:

```
   public class TestThreads implements Runnable {
private static List<String> lis;
public TestThreads(List<String> list)
{
    lis=list;
}
   public void run()
   {
System.out.println("This is thread "+Thread.currentThread().getId());

System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
for(String s:lis)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
   }
   }
```

Update:

it was STATIC list that causes issue, everything works fine after removing it. Appreciate the time and help from Tim and Xiezi !

Comment: I don't understand the question, is your paritions a "Collection<List<String>>"?

Comment: partitions is a list of list<String>, each list<String> contains some strings in orderly fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your new testing codes, 2 things:

1. You may not understand multi-threading very well. They way you output the result can't show anything. You should output the result with the thread Id instead of putting it at the beginning:

   ```
   public void run() {
       for (String s : lis) {
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " : " + s);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Why do you put the list as `static` in the `TestThreads` class? You may be better to check the way of using `static`. And I believe this is the reason. You can try my code which is just the same with yours except for removing the `static`:

   ```
   import java.math.RoundingMode;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
   import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
   import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
   import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
   import com.google.common.math.IntMath;

   public class Test {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           int numOfthreads = 2;
           List<String> originalList = new ArrayList<String>();

           for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
               originalList.add(Integer.toString(i));
           }

           int partitionSize = IntMath.divide(originalList.size(), numOfthreads,
                   RoundingMode.UP);
           List<List<String>> partitions = Lists.partition(originalList,
                   partitionSize);
           List<Callable<Object>> todo = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();
           int count = 0;
           ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors
                   .newFixedThreadPool(numOfthreads);

           for (int i = 0; i < partitions.size(); i++) {
               TestThreads it = new TestThreads(partitions.get(i));

               todo.add(Executors.callable(it));
               System.out.println("Created thread " + count + ", containing: "
                       + partitions.get(i).size() + " files\n");
               for (String s : partitions.get(i)) {
                   System.out.print(s + " ");
               }
               count++;
               System.out.println("\n");
           }

           taskExecutor.invokeAll(todo);

       }

       public static class TestThreads implements Runnable {
           private List<String> lis;

           public TestThreads(List<String> list) {
               lis = list;
           }

           public void run() {
               for (String s : lis) {
                   System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " : " + s);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Update:

it was STATIC list that causes issue, everything works fine after removing it. Appreciate the time and help from Tim and Xiezi !

Comment: Great, you are correct, I left static there which causes issue. now that you pointed out, I remember such thing happend once long time ago.....i just didnt recall what it was. Great help, both Xiezi and Tim, I really appreciate it !!

Comment: I think something wrong with my IE11, im sure i updated my post, but somehow it was yours got updated, but I made changes to mine too. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You need a way to assign the blocks to the different threads.

The simplest way may be to use an `AtomicInteger` to store the "next block" that needs processing. Each thread calls `getAndIncrement()` on the `nextBlock` integer and then processes the relevant block.

For example:

```
static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 100;
AtomicInteger nextBlock = new AtomicInteger(0);


private class Processor implements Runnable {
     public void run() {
          int blockToProcess = nextBlock.getAndIncrement();
          int end = (blockToProcess+1)*BLOCK_SIZE;

          for (int i=BLOCK_SIZE*blockToProcess;i<end;i++) {
              process(data[i]);
          }
     }
}
```

All code from memory so may have a few typos/method names that need correcting/etc.

The important point is the use of the AtomicInteger, this ensures that thread safely each thread gets assigned a different block to process.

I meant to add it to your question, but here will be ok. You tried to do this, which is not doing what you need:

```
final int BLOCK_SIZE = 1; 
AtomicInteger nextBlock = new AtomicInteger(0);
 int blockToProcess =  nextBlock.getAndIncrement(); 
 int endBlocks = (blockToProcess+partitions.size())*BLOCK_SIZE; 
 for(int i=BLOCK_SIZE*blockToProcess;i<endBlocks;i++)
 { 
  Myclass it=new Myclass(l);
  todo.add( Executors.callable(it));
  } 
 taskExecutor.invokeAll(todo);
```

You actually have two options here - since you are creating the tasks ahead of time you can just tell each task at that point what to process. The way I was suggesting each task picks up the next block when it is executed.

To do it the way you are trying here you can forget the AtomicInteger and just do:

```
 for(int i=0;i<partitions.size;i++)
 { 
    Myclass it=new Myclass(partitions.get(i)); // or just MyClass(i) and then MyClass pulls out the list from partitions
    taskExecutor.execute(it);
  }
```

Where

```
 public class MyClass implements Runnable {
       List<String> toProcess;
       MyClass(List<String> toProcess) {
           this.toProcess = toProcess;
       }


       @override
       public void run() {
           // Process the list
       }
 }
```

or

```
 public class MyClass implements Runnable {
       int toProcess;
       MyClass(int toProcess) {
           this.toProcess = toProcess;
       }


       @override
       public void run() {
           // Process the list
           List<String> list = partitions.get(toProcess);
       }
 }
```

Comment: this is what I tried and it still does not work somehow.  final int BLOCK_SIZE = 1;
        AtomicInteger nextBlock = new AtomicInteger(0);int blockToProcess = nextBlock.getAndIncrement();
           int endBlocks = (blockToProcess+partitions.size())*BLOCK_SIZE;

        for(int i=BLOCK_SIZE*blockToProcess;i<endBlocks;i++){ Myclass it=new Myclass(l)
   todo.add( Executors.callable(it));
} taskExecutor.invokeAll(todo);

Comment: java compiler didnt give any error though, where did i wrong?

Comment: Add what you tried to the end of the question so it's formatted properly and I'll take a look.

Comment: I updated my post, and sorry I updated your post accidentally at first.

Comment: Sorry, you are going to have to take one of the two patterns I described and run with it yourself, I can't debug your code for you. Try reading up on how the things I listed work, try stepping through with a debugger or printing out intermediate states, etc.

Comment: sorry, actually, i tried both, and just to clarify that Myclass is another class that extends Thread

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43519/discussion-between-tim-b-and-ikel)

Answer (score 1):

I bet it's simply that your partitioning has a bug in it. Make sure that it's indeed partitioning correctly, or try this (it uses the Guava library to do the partitioning).

```
ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
List<String> input = //input
List<Future<Object>> tickets = new ArrayList<Future<Object>>();
for (List<String> partition : Lists.partition(input, 1000)) {
    Future<Object> ticket = 
        input.submit(Executors.callable(new Myclass(partition)));
    tickets.add(ticket);
}

for(Future<Object> ticket : tickets){
    ticket.get();
}
```

(This example will divide the input into list of length 1000)

Comment: in fact, i did you Guava library to partition, and I output partitions once to see its conetents, it seems my partitons are ok

Comment: @ikel: oh ok. Are you sure that Myclass is indeed using the partition rather than somehow something else, and that the whole input (incl. the partitions) are immutable?